# ',' or ')' expected - long numbers in Enum

Tags: java, enums, long-integer, enumeration

Why does this code not work? I have a long, and a number that's below 2^64 but it doesn't work. My IntelliJ says that there is a ',' or ')' missing. In my Netbeans it does work but not in Intellij - In Netbeans it works if I remove the L from Byte - Gigabyte, because they are below 2^32 limit and work without L, In IntelliJ it gives me a compiler error (see picture) if I have the L on these 2^32 (Byte - GB) or not. Restarting IntelliJ didn't help.

```
public enum Type {

    BYTE (1L), KILOBYTE (1024L), MEGABYTE(1048576L), GIGABYTE(1073741824L), TERABYTES(1099511627776L), PETABYTE(1125899906842624L‬);

    private final long size;

    private Type(long size){
        this.size=size;
    }

    public long getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Type{" +
                "size=" + size +
                '}';
    }
}
```

[image: Here is where the error occours, i have no clue why]

Comment: You have an invisible character related to text direction around the `PETABYTE(1125899906842624L‬);` declaration. Just delete the end of the line as far as that and retype it by hand.

Comment: The invisible character happens to be [U+202C POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202c/index.htm). Also, there's a "c" missing in your school in your bio ;-)

Comment: Not related to your problem:  I would use numbers like `1L << 0`, `1L << 10`, `1L << 20`, `1L << 30`, and so on.  They’re much easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a hidden Unicode character Unicode U+202C after the PETABYTE size declaration, probably a copy/paste trick. Use this online tool to see it:
https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php

Copy your code snippet there and you will see it.

Comment: Thank you, there was an invisble character. But I wrote the code myself (It's just an Enum afterall). No clue how that U+202C got into the code. Now it works.